# StackOverflowException serializing a .netTiers entity

Tags: wcf, stack-overflow, .nettiers

I have a simple WCF service:

```
public Order[] GetOrdersByStatus(int statusid)
{
    OrderService os = new OrderService();
    TList<Order> orders = os.GetByOrderStateID(statusid);

    return orders.ToArray();
}
```

when this returns it throws a StackOverflowException in mscorlib.  Any idea what could be causing this?

The OrderService is a NetTiers generated service and Order is a NetTiers entity object.  when I return the data is already pulled from the database and ready to go.  What besides a bug in WCF could cause a StackOverflowException after I return from my operation?

Comment: Yes, this is very true, to be honest I haven't even looked at the implementation of the NetTiers entities.  Perhaps the problem lies there, I just assumed that NetTiers entities would have been used in this manner and would generate decent code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the implementation of the serialization of the "Order" type is bad, that could be it.

Comment: .netTiers generated entities have an entity key.  That entity key has a property that points back to it's parent, but that property is not marked as [XmlIgnore] or [NonSerialized].  When serializing the entity it created a cycle and the serialization would blow the stack.  Thanks for the help.